# Jquery changevalue or arraypush when checkbox are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input like this(Looping input form) :

```
<input id="check_<?php echo $value->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" type="checkbox" checked class="check_table get-report-filter">
```

and hidden input like this :

```
<input class="hiddenakun" type="hidden" name="hiddenakun" />
```

this my jquery :

```
var akun = [];
$('.get-report-filter').each(function() {
    $('.get-report-filter').on('click', function() {
            akun.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
```

my point is, I want to push each array data checked to `.hiddenakun`, but my code not working, I know it cause every time I write wrong code, `datepicker` wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with `.get()` to create an array of [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) checkboxes values

```
var akun = $('.get-report-filter:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get(); 

//Set hidden value
$('.hiddenakun').val(akun.join(','));
```

If you want to set the value of `checked` event, then bind an event handler

```
var elems = $('.get-report-filter');
elems.on('change', function() {
    var akun = elems.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get(); 

    //Set hidden value
    $('.hiddenakun').val(akun.join(','));
});
```

**Note**, *`datepicker` wont work.* it's due to syntax error.

Comment: dude, u are awesome

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.get-report-filter').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        akun.push($(this).val());
    }
}); 

// It will push the checked checkbox values to akun
```

Answer (score 0):

You need more strict checker finder. Not all checkbox, but checked checboxes. For this purpose you can use pseudo class finder

```
$('.get-report-filter:checked').each
```

Find info here
https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/